# How to get previous date and current date records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

How to get based on `MRLnum` last and previous date records

| MRLNum | CreatedOn | ReviseCode | RequiredQty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SAN-000027-001 | 2/27/2023 | 0 | 100 |
| SAN-000027-001 | 2/28/2023 | 1 | 30 |
| SAN-000027-001 | 3/29/2023 | 1 | 30 |
| SAN-000028-001 | 3/21/2023 | 1 | 30 |
| SAN-000028-001 | 3/23/2023 | 1 | 30 |
| SAN-000028-001 | 3/29/2023 | 1 | 30 |
| SAN-000028-001 | 3/30/2023 | 1 | 30 |

result like this:

| MRLNum | CreatedOn | ReviseCode | RequiredQty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SAN-000027-001 | 2/28/2023 | 1 | 30 |
| SAN-000027-001 | 3/29/2023 | 1 | 30 |
| SAN-000028-001 | 3/29/2023 | 1 | 30 |
| SAN-000028-001 | 3/30/2023 | 1 | 30 |

Comment: We'd love to see what you have tried.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by `"previous date and current date"`? The expected result does not matches with your description of `previous` and `current` date

Comment: in the table based on mrlnum last date and previous date.

Comment: Please show your desired results... And whats `rowInt`?

Comment: use [row_number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to achieve what you want. Do give it a go